# Draw Repeating Bezier Path in UIView

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

Anyone know of a way to draw a repeating Bezier path as a boundary for a UIView?  Ideally would end up looking something like this:

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: That doesnt look like a repeatiting bezier. It is treated as one bezier path.

Comment: You can use tranformation  in it .